# Connecting to Coinex API issue

Tags: rest, get, authorization

I try to connect to Coinex API through a Java program
I follow exact patter that mentioned in below link for authorisation

https://github.com/coinexcom/coinex_exchange_api/wiki/012security_authorization

I MD5 has whole query string that is like below , and put result in authorization in request header parameter

```
 tonce=1635504041595&access_id=XXXX&secret_key=YYYY
```

My intentions is to get account balance so my Get request URL is

https://api.coinex.com/v1//balance/info?tonce=1635504041595&access_id=XXXX

but server return below error

```
{"code": 25, "data": {}, "message": "Signature Incorrect"}
```

Anybody can advice what is the issue , thanks AndyJ

Answer (score 0):

well this is my encode method:

```
public static String encode(String str) {
    try {
        // Generate a summary of MD5 encryption calculations
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

        md.update(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        // digest() finally determines to return the md5 hash value, returning a value of 8 as a string. Because the md5 hash value is a 16-bit hex value, it is actually an 8-bit character.
        // The BigInteger function converts an 8-bit string into a 16-bit hex value, represented by a string; gets a hash value in the form of a string
        String md5 = new BigInteger(1, md.digest()).toString(16);
        //BigInteger will omit 0 and need to be completed to 32 bits
        return fillMD5(md5).toUpperCase();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

and one more thing,
your timestmap should have 10 digits, remove the last 3 "000" like this:

```
Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(timestamp).substring(0, 10));
```